# SQL How to transpose table from row to column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to write sql query transpose table from row to column as picture below
[image]

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do a GROUP BY, case expressions for each aggregation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not using exact names of columns but you can try this,

```
SELECT GOOD2,
       NAME,
       MAX(CASE WHEN [TYPE] = 'BF' THEN VALUE END) BQTY,
       MAX(CASE WHEN [TYPE] = 'RC' THEN VALUE END) BQTY,
       MAX(CASE WHEN [TYPE] = 'ISU' THEN VALUE END) BQTY,
       MAX(CASE WHEN [TYPE] = 'CF' THEN VALUE END) BQTY
FROM   TABLE1
GROUP BY
       GOOD2,
       NAME
```

Comment: You're missing a comma after NAME

Answer (score 2):

With pivoting:

```
SELECT  Goods_ID, 
        Name, UM, 
        ISNULL([B/F],0) as [B/F], 
        ISNULL([REC],0) as [REC],
        ISNULL([ISU],0) as [ISU],
        ISNULL([C/F],0) as [C/F]
FROM (
    SELECT Goods_ID, Name, UM, [Type], NULLIF([In-Qty],0) as Qty
    FROM YourTable 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Goods_ID, Name, UM, [Type],NULLIF([Out-Qty],0)
    FROM YourTable 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Goods_ID, Name, UM, [Type],NULLIF([B-Qty],0)
    FROM YourTable 
    ) as p
PIVOT (
MIN(Qty) FOR [Type] IN ([B/F],[REC],[ISU],[C/F])
) as pvt
```

Output:

```
Goods_ID    Name    UM  B/F     REC     ISU     C/F
CH006       CH006   Kg  11648   11648   0       23296
CH007       CH007   Kg  97584   278400  -315006 60978
```

Answer (score 0):

You just want to group by them. Here is a theoretical example:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name GROUP BY column_name
```

(you need to include all columns in the table in the order you want)

Answer (score 0):

not tested, but should be something like this...

```
select goods_id, name, [B/F], REC, ISU, [C/F] from 
    (select goods_id, name, UM, B-Qty from 
    yourtable ) 
    tbl pivot (sum(B-Qty) for UM in ( [B/F], REC, ISU, [C/F] ) 
    as p
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say you need to use `PIVOT`

See the same **[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server)** with different requirement and almost all ways to achieve your expected output.